# Can't select my image in Illustrator CS6 to fill it with color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, image-trace

I traced an image in image trace, (Illustrator CS6) it is on its own layer and now I can't select it. I've tried with the select tool, the direct select tool, magic wand, lasso to fill it with a different color but nothing works.  I can't drag the eyedropper into it with the color from the fill box, nothing.  Do I need anchor points on it to select it?  How to I get that?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what is going on. Triple check that the layer is not locked, that you have no transparent object above your drawing, and wether it is expanded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Select the image and click the `Expand` Button on the control bar across the top of the screen.

[Click here](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2013/07/image-trace-in-illustrator-a-tutorial-and-guide.html) for the help files about [using Adobe Illustrator's Image Trace feature](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2013/07/image-trace-in-illustrator-a-tutorial-and-guide.html). (or simply tap the <kbd>F1</kbd> key when in the application and ask your question in the help file search box.)